Bed, Bath and Beyond, with the Beyond being some advanced technology?
Trying to remember which movie this is in.  Definitely American Hollywood movie, I just recall a scene where two characters go into a Bed, Bath and Beyond store and one of them asks for the "Beyond" section.  They end up in some back room full of technology, possibly extra-terrestrial stuff.  The second character says something like, "I had no idea they carried stuff like this!" and the first character says something like, "Well, what did you think the 'Beyond' stood for?"
Sorry that's not a lot to go on, but I think it was a pretty mainstream movie so I'm hoping someone remembers this scene.  I'd guess the movie was late 90's/early 2000's, but I'm not 100% positive.

See also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXkwqoEFB0w

Possibly Click from 2006 with Adam Sandler. He finds the magical remote in a Bed, Bath & Beyond inside a storage room called Beyond full of weird gadgets and then another called Way Beyond.


YES.  That's it!  That was bugging me all day.  :o)
